# Refresh UI after Dynamicly adding entry field to stacklayout on stipper value change

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a stepper and i want to add new entry field when the value increment or delete entry on value decrement , i manged to do that but the UI won't refresh directly after the value of the stepper change (i need to click on other UI element first) then the fields will appear , and after clicking in other UI element the stepper will work properly (adding and deleting functionality) which i don't know why it's happening ?!! .

EDIT :
It's look like the problem is with having scroll view .. if i remove it the new fields will added or deleted directly .. but still don't know why .

The xaml page

```
<ScrollView>
    <StackLayout x:Name="StackLayout">
        <Label Text="عدد العناصر المراد اضافتها (اقصى عدد في المرة الواحدة 30)"></Label>
        <Stepper Maximum="30"
                 Minimum="2" 
                 Increment="1" 
                 ValueChanged="Stepper_OnValueChanged" 
                 Value="2"></Stepper>
        <StackLayout x:Name="EntryStackLayout">
            <Entry></Entry>
            <Entry ></Entry>
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Code Behind

```
public partial class AddNewListOfItemsPage : ContentPage
{
    public AddNewListOfItemsPage ()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Stepper_OnValueChanged(object sender, ValueChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.NewValue > e.OldValue) 
        {
            EntryStackLayout.Children.Add(new Entry());
        }
        else
        {
            var childCount = EntryStackLayout.Children.Count;
            EntryStackLayout.Children.RemoveAt(childCount - 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok i found that adding a stackLayout before the scrollView fix the problem

```
 <StackLayout>
    <ScrollView>
        <StackLayout x:Name="StackLayout">
            <Label Text="عدد العناصر المراد اضافتها (اقصى عدد في المرة الواحدة 30)"></Label>
            <Stepper Maximum="30"
                     Minimum="2" 
                     Increment="1" 
                     ValueChanged="Stepper_OnValueChanged" 
                     Value="2"></Stepper>
            <StackLayout x:Name="EntryStackLayout">
                <Entry></Entry>
                <Entry ></Entry>
            </StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</StackLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. Size of elements deep inside ScrollView was not refreshed after layout change (on Android < 4.3).

Specifying height of ScrollView helped (specifying either one of the following for ScrollView in XAML helped):

```
VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
HeightRequest="100"
```